# Collected user information is not saved in database using django framework

Tags: python, django, web

when I try to add details using this form it is not updating to my database.

please help me to solve this issue.

There is no error but the database is not updated.

club.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
     {%ifequal request.user.Isclubmember True%}
        <div class='container'>
        </div>
        {%else%}
        <div class="container">
            <form action="." method="POST">
                {%csrf_token%}
                Profile Pic:
                <input name="image" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" type="file" value=selectimage>
                Phonenumber:
                <input name="userphonenumber" type="number" placeholder="+91 9876543210" >
                <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            </form>
        </div>
        {%endifequal%}
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import  UserProfile, Clubmember
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def club(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            Clubmember.user = request.user
            Clubmember.phone_number = request.POST.get('userphonenumber')
            Clubmember.userphoto = request.FILES.get('image')
            request.user.Isclubmember = True
            request.user.save()
            Clubmember.save()
            return redirect(request,'core:home')
        else:
            return redirect(request,'login_url')
    else:
        return render(request,'core:club')
```

models.py

```
class Clubmember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userphoto = models.ImageField(upload_to="userphotos/%Y/%m",default=False)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    usermoney = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the view like this, it should work.

```
def club(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            club_member = Clubmember()
            club_member.user = request.user
            club_member.phone_number = request.POST.get('userphonenumber')
            club_member.userphoto = request.FILES.get('image')
            request.user.Isclubmember = True
            request.user.save()
            club_member.save()
            return redirect(request,'core:home')
        else:
            return redirect(request,'login_url')
    else:
        return render(request,'core:club')
```

and a better approach is

```
def club(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            club_member = Clubmember(
                user=request.user,
                phone_number=request.POST.get('userphonenumber'),
                userphoto=request.FILES.get('image')
            )
            club_member.save()
            request.user.Isclubmember = True
            request.user.save()
            return redirect(request,'core:home')
        else:
            return redirect(request,'login_url')
    else:
        return render(request,'core:club')
```